# text in one cell how to convert automatic in image to other cell

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have sheet with a text, I want a formula or any script that can convert text into image in next cell automatically. Is their any way to convert cell text(value) into image automatically in google sheet. Can anyone please help me in this. Thanks everyone in advance.

> ```
>   Column A     Column B
>
>  This my text   this is my text ( in image format )
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is for **Excel**.

Click on a cell and run:

```
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveCell.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```